# Cannot find the right camel-cxf dependencies for v3.18.0, e.g. CxfHeaderFilterStrategy, CxfOperationException

Tags: apache-camel, cxf

My application has been using

org.apache.camel.component.cxf.common.header.CxfHeaderFilterStrategy

org.apache.camel.spi.HeaderFilterStrategy.Direction

org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfOperationException

defined by camel-cxf.  But my build fails when using Camel 3.18.0.  What dependencies changes do I need for these classes in 3.18.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying from the Camel 3.18 upgrade guide:

https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3x-upgrade-guide-3_18.html#_camel_cxf

The `camel-cxf` JAR has been split up into SOAP vs REST and Spring and non Spring JARs.

- `camel-cxf-soap`
- `camel-cxf-spring-soap`
- `camel-cxf-rest`
- `camel-cxf-spring-rest`
- `camel-cxf-transport`
- `camel-cxf-spring-transport`

When using Spring Boot then you need to migrate from `camel-cxf-starter` to use SOAP or REST:

- `camel-cxf-soap-starter`
- `camel-cxf-rest-starter`

Comment: Thank https://stackoverflow.com/users/8627215/james-netherton for the answer.  It turned out that not only there are these new jars, the packages were also changed in 3.18.0.  For example, the CxfHeaderFilterStrategy is now in org.apache.camel.component.cxf.transport.header, and CxfOperationException is now in org.apache.camel.component.cxf.common.  The migration guide should have mentioned that.